# How can I use ` use_frameworks!` to a specific cocoapods pod?

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

I know if you are using Cocoapods, you should use all pods as framework or static libraries. It's not possible specify some pods using framework and the others using static library. But I just want to have a try to ask or discussion about this problem. Maybe there will be some tricky solutions. ^_^

I am working on a iOS project, Objective-C as the main development language. Now I want to import a swift framework using Cocoapods, I didn't use `use_frameworks!`, some problems occurs as expected. The Cocoapods version is `1.5.3`, Swift 5.0, is there a way or a new version to solve this problem? How about `Carthage`?

Any discussion is appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

CocoaPods [1.9.0 is adding support](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/9119) for specifying linkage on individual pods.  Until then, the only option is Podfile hacks like [this one](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4338#issuecomment-558547457).